# Growing Penicillium Digitatum Mold

Tags: mycology, growth

I left a cup of tea with Lemmon on my desk and after a while green mold start growing on the water. From my understating this is *Penicillium digitatum*. I gave it some sugar and after one day black spots appeared. I read that it can be little bit dangerous to inhale mold so I wrapped the cup with saran wrap and make some holes in it in order to give the mold oxygen.

1. What do I need to do in order to give the mold better condition to grow?
2. Can it be dangerous growing it?

Comment: What's your goal with this project? You don't really know what you've got in that tea-cup, and DIY dirty dish biology doesn't sound like a great idea in general...

Comment: What makes you think it's specifically *P. digitatum*? *Penicillium* molds are very widespread in the environment, and can be almost impossible to differentiate based on visual appearances alone. That being said, I echo @jakebeal - what is your ultimate purpose in this experiment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place part of the mould into a cut in a piece of citrus fruit to continue its growth. Citrus can also host P. italicum, the below website is one mentioning how to differentiate between them.

http://www.pestnet.org/fact_sheets/citrus_storage_moulds_197.html

**Hazards**.

Aspergillosis: (fungal spores growing in the lungs) which is uncommon.

Asthma: penicillium spores have been associated with increased chance of onset of asthma, and problems with breathing in people with asthma.

There may be other hazards.

I just cite one paper below, but a search using terms of penicillium and asthma shows lots more.

"Household airborne Penicillium associated with peak expiratory flow variability in asthmatic children"

published in :

Annals of allergy, asthma & immunology : official publication of the American College of Allergy, Asthma, & Immunology

by:

Kemp W. Bundy, MD, MBA, Janneane F. Gent, PhD, [...], and Brian P. Leaderer, PhD

doi: 10.1016/S1081-1206(10)60139-1

Comment: thanks. It seems too dangerous to keep growing it. Should I worry that it was in my room for a few days?

Comment: @ziv as long as you're not immune compromised and you haven't been purposely inhaling the fungus, you should be fine.